# Trying to echo JS function in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, quote

I'm trying to echo a js function in HTML string inside PHP echo.

And I can't figure it out :

```
$MY_JS_FUNCTION = '<script type="text/javascript">item + getLastField2()</script>';

if($row2->type == 'text') {
    echo "<li id='item-".$row2->rank."' class='list_item'>";
    echo "<textarea rows='2' id='".$row2->single_id."' cols='90' name='field[".$MY_JS_FUNCTION."]' data-kind='text' >".$row2->content."</textarea>";
    echo "</li>";
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Any ideas to get this work? I think I have so much quotes in it or something like that...

Any help would be very very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It display the code itself literally and not the generated result

Comment: Actually I need to get the '<script>...' inside the input where $MY_JS_FUNCTION is called

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. The line where you echo the `textarea` markup is going to be putting the entire script tag you specify in `$MY_JS_FUNCTION` inside the name attribute of the textarea (e.g., you're going to have `name='field[<script type="text/javascript">item + getLastField2()</script>]'`). This definitely isn't going to do anything for the browser. :) Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I get this : name='field[<script type="text/javascript">item + getLastField2()</script>]' and that's not what I expect.

Actually, I'm trying to put in field[] an id generated by jQuery. I've already to that in a .js file :

$("#add1").live("click", function(){
      $('#reorder2, #reorder3').append("<li id="+ item + getLastField2() +" class='list_item'>" + "<input type='text' name='field["+ getLastField()+"]' value='' id='req' class='dynamic-order' data-kind='title' />" + deletebtn + "</li>");
    });

I need to do the same in PHP

Comment: You can't invoke JS function from PHP or vice-versa. You're trying to have PHP calculate some ID value via JS function, which doesn't work. Describe what you want to achieve in *detail* and someone will present a different way to achieve what you want because this is far from being usable.

Comment: I ve put the code here : http://pastebin.com/uKq1pXYA

Comment: am i the only one who is confused just by the first line :S ? and for the record, PHP doesn't speak JavaScript, it only speaks PHP so it doesn't know what you are talking about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd reccommend storing the name in the database as well.
Then you can use $row2->name to insert the right name

Comment: I can't store my JS function in the DB it's useless I just need to call the JS inside the input field where $MY_JS_FUNCTION is called

Comment: Could you please post the contents of the JS function? if youre only trying to change the name of the fields i'd recommend using jQuery to do so

Comment: Yes off course, I think jQuery could do the job, could you tell me how ? Here's the code : http://pastebin.com/ZE3S2UXV

Comment: if you still have this problem, please mail me a working link (since the pastebin link isn't working anymore) to tjeerd@Valkyrius.com

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$MY_JS_FUNCTION` contains an HTML `<script>` tag with some (strange) JavaScript code (missing a semi-colon). Based on your code the `echo` on line 5 results in this HTML:

```
<textarea ... name='field[<script type="text/javascript">item + getLastField2()</script>]' ... >...</textarea>
```

This is definitively not valid HTML. And there is your problem...

Answer (score 0):

It appears your intent is to echo that JS so that when the page loads, the JS actually sets the value of the name field for that textarea.  If that's the case, a simpler way might be something like this:

```
$MY_JS_FUNCTION = '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("myTextArea").name = item + getLastField2()</script>';

if($row2->type == 'text') {
    echo "<li id='item-".$row2->rank."' class='list_item'>";
    echo "<textarea rows='2' id='".$row2->single_id."' cols='90' id='myTextArea' data-kind='text' >".$row2->content."</textarea>";
    echo $MY_JS_FUNCTION;
    echo "</li>";
    echo '<br />';
}
```

That will produce valid HTML.  The JS function will fire once that line is reached and update the "name" value to whatever the result of the function is.  Be sure to add the "id" field so that the JS knows which element to target.

Comment: Ok thx for your answer, that may do the trick but I need to retrieve the result of a function for the "name" attribute (item + getLastField2()) here's the js function that I need to call for the "name" attribute : http://pastebin.com/ZE3S2UXV

Comment: The JS in the link you sent needs to appear in your HTML file somewhere above the JS I posted in my response.  Note that in the JS you sent, the function name is getLastField(), not getLastField2() which was in your original post.  Assuming the correct function name, once the JS in my response fires it will create the name based on item + getLastField and assign that value to the name attribute of the textarea.

Comment: Yes I've put my function above my code in a <script> tag then I used your code and that doesn't work :( I've tried something like : document.getElementById("myTextArea").name = "test" and that works fine but with getLastField2() it doesn't work. any ideas?

Comment: I think the getLastField2() item is not found maybe

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors?  Is the code for getLastField2() the same as the code for getLastField() (which was the function name you in this link: http://pastebin.com/ZE3S2UXV)

Comment: No errors here's the full code : http://pastebin.com/mxEXBUSi btw thanks for your help ;)

Comment: The line var fields = jQuery('.dynamic-order'), fieldName; looks suspicious - I'm not JS expert but I don't think that's correct.  I'm assuming fields is supposed to be an array is that right?

Comment: Yes fields is an array, the code you gave me works fine it seems to have a bug with my getLastField function (this function is also used on a js file elsewhere and works fine)

Comment: Please post the question regarding the JS bug as a new question so that people more knowledgeable about JS can help you with that.  I'm not entirely sure what that function is supposed to be doing.