# Creating dynamic elements with Javascript event using echo in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

It's simple if the code is written in Javascript (between the `<script>` and `</script>`, but I'm encountering a problem like this (render dynamic content using echo in PHP):

```
echo "<label onclick='showContent(\"".$content."\")'>Click me</label>"
```

and I also tried this:

```
echo '<label onclick="showContent("'.$content.'")">Click me</label>'
```

The problem is that `$content` can contain many characters like " (double quote), ' (single quote)... Generally, it contains HTML code.

If it is a normal sentence, the code above will work well, it renders a label of 'Click me' and I can click it to run the function `showContent()`, but if it contains HTML code, it can render the label however I can't run the function `showContent()` when I click on it. I think there is some problem with quotes here. I tried replacing all the single and double quotes in $content with " or \"  and ' or \'   but it still doesn't work, even in some cases, the label of 'Click me' can't be rendered properly, instead of that it shows me almost the code behind.

I'm really stuck at this (already for hours), please give me a solution. Your help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Check the PHP function addslashes() to escape the quotes : http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: What's in showContent()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282708/trying-to-echo-js-function-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, but I want to emphasize that $content can contain HTML code and are you sure with only addslashes() can solve my problem? I tried it but my echo can't even render the label properly, instead, it showed me a part of the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<label onclick="showContent('.$content.')">Click me</label>'
```

Comment: Sorry, it will work in some case, the $content's value varies as much as you can imagine, you can think of this, I have a textarea in a form, I want I can paste any HTML code (copy from another editor, for example) to that textarea and submit the form to a php page, this page contains code to render a button (or a label with onclick event as I asked) on which the user can click to show what s/he sent. This is a very simple page, I've done this many times since the time I learned PHP but for normal text, this case is for HTML code (with multiline possibly).

Comment: @king-king Could you maybe add the showContent function to the question. It is rather hard to help you working semi-blind. Thanks.